# Tangent plane through $(1,1,1)$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Determine the equation of the tangent plane to the surface $x^2y+z^2y-2z-y=-1$ that passing through the point $(1,1,1)$. Is there any point on the surface where the tangent plane is parallel to the $xy$ plane? Which?

$$f'_1=2xy,\ f'_2=x^2+z^2-1\\$$
Equation of tangent plane: $Z=f(a,b)+f'_1(a,b)(x-a)+f'_2(a,b)(y-b)$

$$Z=1+2(x-1)+z^2(y-1)=2x+z^2y-z^2-1$$

Or shall I also put $z=1$ in $f'_2(a,b)$?

$$Z=1+2(x-1)+1(y-1)=2x+y-2$$

Comment: with $z^2$, it wouldn't be a plane

Comment: It is a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ so it is in form $t=f(x,y,z)$. As consequence the hyperplane will have equation $\Gamma: t-f(x_0,y_0,z_0)= \langle \nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0),(x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0) \rangle$

Comment: Alternatively write the polynomial around $(1,1,1)$: $(y-1)(z-1)^2+(z-1)^2+2(y-1)(z-1)+(x-1)^2(y-1)+2(x-1)(y-1)+(y-1)+(x-1)^2+2(x-1)=0$ and cut the higher order terms: $(y-1)+2(x-1)=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula does not account for the z-dimension, computing the directional derivatives

$f_1'(x,y,z) = 2xy$

$f_2'(x,y,z) = x^2 + z^2 - 1$

$f_3'(x,y,z) = 2zy - 2$

And evaluating these at $(1, 1, 1)$

$f_1'(1, 1, 1) = 2$

$f_2'(1, 1, 1) = 1$

$f_3'(1, 1, 1) = 0$

The equation of the tangent plane at $(a, b, c)$ is given by

$ 0 = (x-a)f_1'(a, b, c) + (y-b)f_2'(a, b, c) + (z-c)f_3'(a, b, c) $

$ 0 = (x-1)f_1'(1, 1, 1) + (y-1)f_2'(1, 1, 1) + (z-1)f_3'(1, 1, 1) $

$ 0 = 2(x-1) + y-1 $

$ 3 = 2x + y $

note that in general the plane is not parallel to the $xy$-plane and you do have to compute the directional derivatives for every input. In this example since $f_3'(1, 1, 1) = 0$ we have that it is in fact parallel to the $xy$-plane.

Comment: Did you mean $z-c$ and $(z-1)f_3'$ where you typed $y-c$ and $(y-1)f_3'$, respectively?

Comment: Yes I did, thanks for pointing that out :) I have corrected it

Comment: This made it very clear. Thanks for your time!